# Does python function str.find() returns string rather than index num

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 'hello world'
a.find('wor')
# result: 5
```

which is index 5 .

this is not what i want. i want to return that particular sub string which has been found on index 5.

In Python how to search / find sub-string in a string that returns that sub-string if found not an index number.

Is there way out.....

Comment: but you already have this substring - it is `wor`

Comment: What's the expect output?

Comment: yes if found print that substring like wor

Comment: `if a.find('wor') > -1: print('wor')` or `if 'wor' in a: print('wor')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like this:

```
myString = "hello world"
found = a.find('wor')
a = a[found: found+3]
```

of course just a simple example but should give you the idea, it uses python list slicing functionality, you can go one step further:

```
def find_substring(string, substring):
    pos = string.find(substring)
    return string[pos: pos + len(substring)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that strings in Python are immutable, so if you somehow extract a substring from a source string a new string has to be created by copying the characters from the source string. It's not like in some other languages where you can simply return a reference into the source string.

To do what you want, I'd simply use the `in` operator. Eg:

```
a = 'hello world'
data = ('wor', 'WOR', 'hell', 'help')

for s in data:
    print(s, s if s in a else None)
```

**output**

```
wor wor
WOR None
hell hell                                                                                                                                      
help None
```

Or if you prefer a function:

```
def found(src, substring):
    return substring if substring in src else None

for s in data:
    print(s, found(a, s))
```

---

In case you're unfamiliar with Python's `yes_value if some_condition else no_value` syntax (aka a conditional expression), here's that function re-written using a more "traditional" `if ... else` block:

```
def found(src, substring):
    if substring in src:
        return substring
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: its going out of my scope. i m just a beginner dear

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoGiordano. :) Also, the `in` operator has less overheads than using a function / method call, so it's a Good Idea to use it rather than using `str.find` or `str.index` when you don't actually need the index.

Comment: is it faster? isn't the in operator just going to call the iterator of the string? but anyway yes the in operator is way more pythonic.

Comment: @MarcoGiordano: True, under the hood, `in` invokes the object's `__contains__` method, or just iterates over the container if the container does not define `__contains__`,  but IIRC this still works out faster than making an explicit Python method call which then goes on to do the same thing. IOW, using `in` saves one level of function calling, and function calls in Python are relatively slow.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks a lot for the information, this is quite interesting, i did not write an iteratable in like ages, so is a good refresher. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This fulfills your stated requirement:

```
>>> import re
>>> (re.search('wor','Hello world')).group(0)
'wor'
>>>
```

(Read the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) for `re.search` for more information)